# Aorus Z490 lm-sensors: Did sensors-detect corrupt my temperatures?

Tags: temperature, sensors, lm-sensors

in linux I ran sensors-detect, which I now learned is a potentially dangerous program. Fortunately I am 90% confident I accepted all of the defaults. I want to be completely sure.
I just got my pc and temperatures are spiking wildly. Temperatures go from 25C to 45C. This can happen when I open a new application or a new window. I have an Aorus Z490 motherboard. Is this temperature spiking possibly related to sensors-detect?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I am using 20.04